# How do you efficiently run test automation against multiple servers for validation?

Tags: testing, automation, webserver, watin

Scenario:  25 Web Servers with the same web application.

We are using Visual Studio and WatiN for our automation and right now we have basicly three tests that run. Within the tests while its running it iterates through each server.

Test: SignIn
  ForEach Server
     Get Server x
     Run Test

In this case this test would run 25 time loops and if each test take 2 minutes to run that is almost an hour to validate.  WAY TOO LONG!!! :(

What I would like to be able to do is spread this work out across as multiple test agents.

The problem is that this test can only run on one agent because it is one test.

The approach I am avoiding is, creating a test specific to each server and duplication that would cause.

Test: SignIn server 1
     Run Test on Server 1

Test: SignIn server 2
     Run Test on Server 2

and so on, 25 times

I hoping that some one can share what they have implemented around this type of set up.

Comment: Slightly odd idea, but how about run half the tests in IE and half in Firefox?

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on a project for just over a year now that does exactly this!

We've got about 400 nunit tests that use watin to test our company website.  The first version of the project used 10 virtual machines to run tests (so can run 10 concurrent tests).

The new version will use an application I've found called Sandboxie - http://www.sandboxie.com.  This app allows you to run an application in a sandbox (which means the cookies from one test can't interfere with those of another).  There's a .net wrapper for it, (I added the dynamically linked version at the bottom) - http://www.sandboxie.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?t=9041

After some messing about I realised that sandboxie wouldn't work very well on a VM (running a virtual application space on a virtual machine?!?  Derp).  So now we have 4 physical machines with (currently) 10 sandboxes (so can now run 40 concurrent tests).  Here's an overview of the project: -

```
Web UI.  Requests test to be run by...
-> Test Server (windows service on server).  Adds requests to database and passes on to...
   -> Test controller 1 (windows service on client 1)
      -> Test runner (console app on client 1) in Sandbox 01
      -> ...
      -> Test runner (console app on client 1) in Sandbox 10
   -> Test controller 2 (windows service on client 2)
      -> Test runner (console app on client 1) in Sandbox 01
      -> ...
      -> Test runner (console app on client 1) in Sandbox 10
   -> Test controller 3 (windows service on client 3)
      -> Test runner (console app on client 1) in Sandbox 01
      -> ...
      -> Test runner (console app on client 1) in Sandbox 10
   -> Test controller 3 (windows service on client 4)
      -> Test runner (console app on client 1) in Sandbox 01
      -> ...
      -> Test runner (console app on client 1) in Sandbox 10
```

If you've got any questions I'd be happy to help!

Phil

Answer (score 0):

If you run these tests in parallel you should be able to run them all concurrently and finish running all tests in 2 minutes.

What we do is use mbUnit with selenium tests (to run them in parallel) against the selenium grid (which can actually execute these in parallel).

Comment: I was hoping to not have to switch over to selenium.  But if it that's the only solution that comes up I'll give it a go to get selenium grid and the bonus of xpath.   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Running tests in parallel on the same machine would definitely be a cool option.  But with Watin it may pose problems since multiple IE instances open at the same time, hitting the same website, might interfere with each other.

I would suggest trying to launch two of your Watin tests at once and see if the browsers get confused.  (That is, if the second browser reuses the same cookies/state/etc as the first and breaks the test.)

If they don't have issues, then you can try scaling up to 5, 10, or however many concurrent runs the machine can stand, and possibly be on your way. :)

But if the browsers do interfere with each other, you might look in to ways to make Watin launch browsers in a way that keeps their state separate (I think the Watir folks have some some work in this area, so it's probably possible with WatiN.)

A completely different option:

If you have multiple client machines to run tests on, you might check out using Jenkins or Hudson to schedule your Watin tests.

http://jenkins-ci.org/

Even two or three machines running the same test suite concurrently would cut down your total test run time a lot.

Jenkins has become an invaluable part of my testing process.  I've found it to be a great tool for scheduling test jobs to run at fixed times of day or upon changes in source control.

Supposedly there are ways to pass params to a Jenkins job (such as the server address and login credentials in your case), so you can probably take advantage of that to avoid duplication.  And failing that, you could try making a Jenkins job for each server you want to run a test against.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into  Microsoft Test Controller & Agents? If you are running "WatiN" tests using MSTest it would be like running a unit test.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243155.aspx

> Using the Test Controller and Test Agent with Unit Tests
>
> Once you have installed a test controller and one or more agents, you
>   can then specify the use of a remote execution with the test
>   controller in the test setting that you use when you run your load
>   tests. Additionally, you can specify the data and diagnostic adapters
>   to use with the role that is associated with the agents in the test
>   setting. For more information, see How to: Create a Test Setting for a
>   Distributed Load Test and Setting Up Machines and Collecting
>   Diagnostic Information Using Test Settings.

On a side note - you can use jquery selectors in the latest WatiN.

Answer (score 0):

I have this kind of a setup but I am using NUnit. The test infrastructure that I have consists of a test controller that builds the test assemblies (.dlls) and copies them over to the web servers. And then using PSEXEC, the tests are remotely invoked on all the web servers. 
NUnit is installed on the web servers, however, I dont think that is a requirement and you might be able to use the NUnit Test Runner from a xcopied version without having installed it.

Along with the test assemblies, there is another executable that is copied over to the web server from the test controller, that publishes the results to HP Quality Center and also sends out an email notification containing the test results.

Since you are using MSTest (my guess as you mentioned Visual Studio to run the tests), you might want to go through this [Develop and run MSTest unit tests in Visual Studio 2010 without including .vsmdi and .testsettings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311541/develop-and-run-mstest-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2010-without-including-vsmdi)